# Maven adds class files of snapshot dependencies

Tags: maven-2

on my Windows machine I do have several proeject that I build with maven. At the moment they are all in SNAPSHOT-State. When I build a project that relies on one of the other projects maven always adds the class files of the other projects to the jar.
If I build the project on my CI-Server this problem does not occur. Does anyone have an idea why maven adds the class files to my jar?

I'm using maven 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

> When I build a project that relies on one of the other projects maven always adds the class files of the other projects to the jar.

This is not a default behavior and, if it happens, you're somehow telling Maven to do so. If you want to hunt potential discrepancies, check the `effective-pom`, the `effective-settings`, the `active-profiles` using the following goals on **both** machines:

- `help:effective-pom`
- `help:effective-settings`
- `help:active-profiles`

Also double check **how** Maven is invoked on the CI machine (extra command line parameter, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Unfortunately the results of the commands on both of the two machines look exactly the same. Only the paths are different. I took another look at the jar file created on my windows machine. Only the class files that the project I build depends on are included in the build.

Comment: @soeren Sadly, I'm afraid it will be hard to help further without a pom allowing to reproduce.

Comment: I finally found the problem. It had nothing to do with maven but with the installed jdk. I usedon a pretty old version 6 jdk. With the new version of the jdk it works fine now. Anyway thank you for your help. I appreciate that.